# Is the number of exposed vertices equal for different maximum matchings?

Tags: graph-theory

Given two maximum matchings $M$ and $M'$ on a given undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ (not necessarily bipartite), with $M$ and $M'$ having, respectively, $p$ and $p'$ exposed vertices (i.e. vertices not used by $M$ or $M'$ accordingly), must we have $p=p'$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the matchings $M$ and $M'$ cover $e$ edges then they will cover $2e$ vertices, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
2e+p=2e+p'.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Haha of course...